# JUnit test suite hangs while executing in docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, serenity-bdd, zalenium

I have set up Docker, Zalenium and Jenkins in a Linux Virtual Machine to run my automation test suite which has Parallel and Non-Parallel test cases. My suite have 800 scenarios but i execute the 30 most important only. When Jenkins start the job, it runs the Parallel test cases first and then the Non-Parallel in 5 containers and at the end it serenity:aggregate the two reports to one full report.  I know that the aggregation works fine because I've tested it running 1 parallel and 1 Non-parallel test and the number of containers is not the problem. When I am trying to execute my 30 test cases, after 20-24 test case the job is starting to hang forever. So Non-parallel test cases never run and some of the parallel also. I tried to run the suite in command line but i face the same problem, which means that its not a Jenkins problem. Anyone is facing the same issue?

Comment: What happens if you run your test suite on your laptop, without any docker containers? Does it work or it still hangs?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it does work.